# Declare matrix at file scope, dimensions from user input? C

Tags: c, matrix, global-variables, global-scope

I have a program based on a matrix and need various functions to be able to access this matrix and it's dimensions, which I get from the user. I've managed to do it by passing them as arguments to each separate function, but that doesn't seem efficient.

When I try to declare this:

```
int lin, col;
char matrix[lin][col];
```

I get an error: *variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope*. I'm guessing it's because at that point, I haven't asked the user for 'lin' and 'col'? My question is: is there a way to make my matrix of variable dimensions have global scope? Or a way to access this matrix and dimensions without passing them as arguments to various functions?

Comment: Why you can't use pointers with dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: If you cannot use dynamic allocation, just put greater values than needed.

Comment: I hadn't yet learned about dynamic memory allocation. :) Since it was mentioned here, I googled and figured out what it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
char **matrix;
```

Read rows `r` and columns `c` as input from the user.

Then do :

```
*matrix[c]=malloc(sizeof(matrix[r][c]); //You get contiguous memory here
```

Then you access the matrix like matrix[x][y] , the same way you access a 2D array.

At the end of the day, clear the memory allocated :

```
clear(matrix);
```

> Or a way to access this matrix and dimensions without passing them as
>   arguments to various functions?

Well, yes . You usually you pass the arguments like below :

```
void print_matrix(char** matrix_copy,int rows,int cols)
{
//Access the matrix using matrix_copy[x][y] format
}
```

You can just pass the matrix from `main()` like below :

```
print_matrix(matrix,r,c); // As simple as that.
```

**Since you don't need arguments you need a workaround** which is simple.

Declare

```
char **matrix;
int r,c; // rows & columns
```

outside all the functions, so that they are accessible across the program.
In other words declare them in file scope. But in this case make sure that you access the `matrix` only after it is allocated some space using `malloc`.

Comment: This is probably the worst solution. It has, like, _zero_ memory locality for the data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :  Spatial locality may be guaranteed if the op has a small size matrix spanning only a few bytes/characters

Comment: Quite the opposite because you have an additional layer of indirection. That's the problem. Speaking generally, double-pointers = bad.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Memory Allocation is a viable solution to your problem, as sjsam said.
The only thing I would like to point out is that the code can look like this:

```
int i,lin,col;
char **matrix;
matrix=malloc(lin * sizeof(char*));
//check for NULL
for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
    matrix[i]=malloc(col * sizeof(char));
    //again,check for NULL
}
```

Then again, to free your allocated memory, you do:

```
for(i=0;i<lin;i++)
    free(matrix[i]);
free(matrix);
```

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: In this case memory allocated is not contiguous, ie it is fragmented.
You get slow crappy code that burns.and crashes .

Comment: Yes you are right but as the OP mentioned she is a beginner C programmer, I thought a simpler code might help her understand about pointers and the "malloc" function. Thank you for pointing that out though!

Comment: This is not simpler either.